# Does BottomNavigationBar require IndexedStack widgets? If so, they load all at once, which is annoying

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

- I want a BottomNavigationBar
- I currently do this, and to prevent the BottomNavigationBar from reloading each time when going to a different screen, I use IndexedStack widgets
- Because I used IndexedStacked widgets, whenever the app starts, it runs all the widgets in the entire app which is annoying. I only want a widget to run if I am on that screen.
- How can I modify/fix this where I can use the BottomNavigationBar but not have this IndexedStack widgets running all at once

Comment: it is not a problem.. when some `index` of widgets are in active. they will not rendered on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried using `StatefulWidget`s as your tabs ? They don't refresh when you visit some other screen and come back. Their state `persists` as well.

Comment: @NisanthReddy maybe there is a misunderstanding. The issue I have is with the BottomNavigationBar reloading if if I apply it to each screen, where if I go to another screen, the BottomNavigationBar reloads. So I ended up using IndexedStack for my screens that way the BottomNavigationBar does not reload when going to different screens. But I think you are talking about screens versus my BottomNavigation bar refreshing.

Comment: Honestly, I am still confused. would you be able to add example screenshots explaining some flow.

Comment: @NisanthReddy Say you have (2) screens, and for each screen/widget, you have a bottomnavbar, if you go from one screen to another, the entire page including the bottomnavbar will reload, this does not look good as I only want the body/middle/screen content to change, and keep the bottomnavbar from ever reloading. So this is why I used indexed stack widgets, so when I hit one button on the bottomnavbar, it just switches the widget/screen-content but the bottomnavbar never refresh/reloads which looks proper. Does that make sense so far?

Comment: Oh I see. You mean to say, you have the same bottombar on both pages, right ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy yes I currently and want to continue, having the same bottomnavbar on all pages throughout the app for all screens

Comment: Got it, but not sure how that can be implemented. Let's see if someone comes up with something.

Answer (score 0):

you can try another approach to keep state in a page:

```
// 1. AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
class _PageState extends State<_HomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<_HomePage> {
  // 2. 
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //3. 
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(...
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [LazyLoadIndexedStack](https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_indexed_stack/example). It allows lazy loading.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34293005)